# Condition regarding a composite index in an LP problem?

Tags: notation, linear-programming

In an LP model, I have a decision variable $x$ with a composite index, i.e. $x_{i \delta}$, where $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\delta \in \{ -, + \}$.

In the following constraint of the problem, I want to add the condition that $i \delta$ is not equal to $j \theta$, (i.e. the two $x$ variables do not have the same composite index -- please see examples below):

$A_{i \delta}x_{i \delta} + A_{j \theta}x_{j \theta} \leq C$,
where $A_{i \delta}, A_{j \theta}, C$ are constants.

I considered expressing the constraint as:

$A_{i \delta}x_{i \delta} + A_{j \theta}x_{j \theta} \leq C, i \delta \neq j \theta$,

but I am not sure that is correct.

Another approach could be to express it as:

$A_{i \delta}x_{i \delta} + A_{j \theta}x_{j \theta} \leq C, i \neq j \lor \delta \neq \theta$,

but I am not sure if logical OR conditions can be included in the conditions of a linear constraint in an LP problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example cases where $i \delta$ is not considered equal to $j \theta$:

- $x_{1 +}$ and $x_{1 -}$
- $x_{1 +}$ and $x_{2 +}$
- $x_{1 +}$ and $x_{2 -}$

Example case where  $i \delta$ is considered equal to $j \theta$:

- $x_{1 +}$ and $x_{1 +}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your logical OR is acceptable in an index set for constraints.  I think the following is more readable:
$(i,\delta)\not=(j,\theta)$.
But your proposed $i\delta\not=j\theta$ looks instead like multiplication.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just to confirm, you suggest writing the constraint as follows:
$A_{i \delta}x_{i \delta} + A_{j \theta}x_{j \theta} \leq C, (i, \delta) \neq (j,\theta)$.

Do you believe this will cause any confusion, considering that the composite index is written as $x_{i \delta}$ in the variable, but in the condition of the constraint we express it as a tuple $(i, \delta)$? Or is this a "standard" way to express such cases?

Comment: Yes, this is standard, just like referring to the $(i,j)$ entry in a matrix $A$ as $A_{ij}$.